# SharePoint SuiteBar Customization (UserMenu) Issue

Tags: sharepoint, drop-down-menu, sharepoint-2010, menuitem, sharepoint-2013

I have customized the user menu with direct links for My Profile (renamed “About me”), Edit Profile, My Page, and Sign Out.

I have pointed the links in the drop down menu to the following links below… (My Page and Sign Out work).. but the other two to not.

1) My Profile: “http://my.test.net/_layouts/15/Person.aspx”
  a. Took me to: http://my.test.net/_layouts/15/start.aspx#//_layouts/15/Person.aspx

2) Edit Profile: “http://my.test.net/_layouts/15/EditProfile.aspx” (I have also tried “/EditProfile.aspx”)
  a. Took me to: http://my.test.net/_layouts/15/start.aspx#//_layouts/15/EditProfile.aspx

3) I have also tried alternatives for the links for number 1 and 2:
  a. My Profile (/Person.aspx)
   - This takes me to: http://my.test.net/_layouts/15/start.aspx#//Person.aspx
  b. Edit Profile (/EditProfile.aspx)
   - This takes me to: http://my.test.net/_layouts/15/start.aspx#//EditProfile.aspx

Anyone know of possible problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate this feature at Site level By using following steps:
 Site Settings  -  Site Actions -   Manage Site Features
Deactivate Minimal Download Strategy Feature.